# Moodle Softaculous Installation: MySQL Syntax error

Tags: moodle, mysql-error-1064, softaculous

I`m installing Moodle to a second domain inside the CPanel, using softaculous.
It works with the primary domain.. but it should be installed to the second one instead.

Error Code:

```
Could not make the query numbered : 6
MySQL Error No : 1064
MySQL Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''.$row_format.' COMMENT='Table to store presets data' AUTO_INCREMENT=3' at line 21
```

My hosting company told me to install to install to subdomain instead, however, this failed with error "Unable to generate kids and private keys, hence can not install Moodle 4.2".

The company told me to install to the root, but it failed as well (returning the same "first" problem, which happens when I install to the domain or to a sub-directory.
I tried Moodle 4.2.2 and 4.1.5 as well, using Softaculous and PHP version 8.2 .
***The installation succeeds only if I install to the main domain.***
( I have two domains in one CPanel account, each domain has its own folder)

Error message tells it`s a syntax problem.. but it seems to be another problem.
Any help?
Thanks in advance.
...........................................
Update:
in case it matters, this is the path of the second domain, set by the hosting provider (this in uncontrollable/ non editable in softaculous)
Path
/home2/cpanel-account-name/the-sencod-domain/
URL
https://the-second-domain/

Comment: `$row_format` doesn't exist in the source code for Moodle 4.2.2 or Moodle 4.1.5, so I'm guessing its a softaculous script rather than Moodle - the comment `Table to store presets data` does exist in the Moodle code though, its for the table `adminpresets`